# Error with SelectedNodeChanged Event in Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, treeview

I have two tables in DB:

```
CATALOGBOOK(idCA, nameCA);// kind of book
BOOK(idBOOK, nameBOOK, idCA);// info about one book
```

TreeView after loaded data from DB:

```
+nameCA1
  -nameBOOK1
  -nameBOOK2
+nameCA2
  -nameBOOK1
  -nameBOOK2
.....
```

I also have a textbox in my webform. I use `SelectedNodeChanged Event` for showing book's name in that textbox when I select a treenode `nameBOOK[j]`.  SelectedNodeChanged Event worked fine with the first `nameCA[1]`, but it has an error when I select a treenode `nameBOOK[j]` in `nameCA[2],nameCA[3],...`

I want to load data from DB into TreeView:

```
+nameCA1
  -nameBOOK1
  -nameBOOK2
+nameCA1
  -nameBOOK1
  -nameBOOK2
.....
```

Function to load data from DB into TreeView:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadTree();
}

private void LoadTree()
{
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    string sql = "select * from CATALOGBOOK";
    DataTable catalog = l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < catalog.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TreeNode TN = new TreeNode();
        TN.Text = catalog.Rows[i][1].ToString();//type of book
        TreeNodeSelectAction treeNodeSelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
        TN.SelectAction = treeNodeSelectAction;
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(TN);

        string sql1 = "select * from BOOK where idCA=" + catalog.Rows[i][0].toString();
        DataTable book = l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql1);
        for (int j = 0; j < book.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            TreeNode CN = new TreeNode(book.Rows[j][1].ToString(), book.Rows[j][0].ToString());
            CN.Text = book.Rows[j][1].ToString();//name of book
            CN.Value = book.Rows[j][0].ToString();//id of book
            TN.ChildNodes.Add(CN);
        }
    }
}//end of loadtree();

public void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox1.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value.ToString();
}
```

The problem I got is in line:`this.TextBox1.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value.ToString();`

```
 <asp:TreeView OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" ID="TreeView1"  runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" 
                    Width="183px">
                        <HoverNodeStyle BorderStyle="Inset" />
                        <LeafNodeStyle Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller" />
                        <LevelStyles>
                            <asp:TreeNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="False" />
                            <asp:TreeNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" />
                            <asp:TreeNodeStyle Font-Italic="True" Font-Underline="False" />
                        </LevelStyles>
                        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Overline="False" Font-Underline="True" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
```

Is there any mistake???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load items on page load and on post back you don't need to load it again, you will lost selected values if you re load it again on each page load

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       if(!Page.IsPostBack)
              LoadTree();
   }
```

Comment: Damith: I set TreeView.collapseAll() as default; when I click on a treenode-> the page load and selected node and all nodes collapse again. I just want to close other nodes except the selected node? How?

Comment: @VyClarks you better ask new question